# How to save image from URL into device photo gallery using ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new to ionic and I am developing application using ionic in the application. I need to download the image to the user device when user click on download button. I searched a lot but I am not able to find any proper solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Transfer` [plugin](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/transfer/) from `ionic-native`.

```js
import { Transfer } from 'ionic-native';

declare var cordova: any;

download() {
    const fileTransfer = new Transfer();
    let url = 'http://www.example.com/file.pdf';
    
    fileTransfer.download(url, cordova.file.dataDirectory + 'file.pdf').then((entry) => {
        console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
    }, (error) => {
        // handle error
    });
}
```