# Downlaod an Online image in Ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, file-transfer

I am quite new to Ionic, I am trying to create a function that would be able to download an image in my android device from a url. My function is been called when the user press the download file button in my storage.html the source code is the following:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      File Transfer Example
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>
      Ionic 3 File Transfer Example
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      <img src="https://cdn.houseplans.com/product/o2d2ui14afb1sov3cnslpummre/w1024.jpg?v=15" alt="Cute Pug">
      <button ion-button (click)="downloadImage('w1024.jpg')" color="secondary">Download File</button>
      <button ion-button (click)="retrieveImage('pug.jpg')" color="secondary">Retrieve downloaded image</button>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

the function is the downloadImage(image) located in my storage.ts, the source is the following:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, Platform, AlertController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Transfer, TransferObject} from '@ionic-native/transfer';
import {File} from '@ionic-native/file';

declare var cordova: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'storage-home',
  templateUrl: 'storage.html',
  providers: [Transfer, TransferObject, File]
})

export class StoragePage {

  storageDirectory: string = '';

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public platform: Platform, private transfer: Transfer, private file: File, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // make sure this is on a device, not an emulation (e.g. chrome tools device mode)
      if(!this.platform.is('cordova')) {
        return false;
      }

      if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
        this.storageDirectory = cordova.file.documentsDirectory;
      }
      else if(this.platform.is('android')) {
        this.storageDirectory = cordova.file.dataDirectory;
      }
      else {
        // exit otherwise, but you could add further types here e.g. Windows
        return false;
      }
    });
  }

  downloadImage(image) {

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {

      const fileTransfer: TransferObject = this.transfer.create();

      const imageLocation = `${cordova.file.applicationDirectory}https://cdn.houseplans.com/product/o2d2ui14afb1sov3cnslpummre/w1024.jpg?v=15${image}`;

      fileTransfer.download(imageLocation, this.storageDirectory + image).then((entry) => {

        const alertSuccess = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: `Download Succeeded!`,
          subTitle: `${image} was successfully downloaded to: ${entry.toURL()}`,
          buttons: ['Ok']
        });

        alertSuccess.present();

      }, (error) => {

        const alertFailure = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: `Download Failed!`,
          subTitle: `${image} was not successfully downloaded. Error code: ${error.code}`,
          buttons: ['Ok']
        });

        alertFailure.present();

      });

    });

  }

  retrieveImage(image) {

    this.file.checkFile(this.storageDirectory, image)
      .then(() => {

        const alertSuccess = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: `File retrieval Succeeded!`,
          subTitle: `${image} was successfully retrieved from: ${this.storageDirectory}`,
          buttons: ['Ok']
        });

        return alertSuccess.present();

      })
      .catch((err) => {

        const alertFailure = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: `File retrieval Failed!`,
          subTitle: `${image} was not successfully retrieved. Error Code: ${err.code}`,
          buttons: ['Ok']
        });

        return alertFailure.present();

      });
  }
```

All the necessary plugins have been imported and i created an apk. File to install it in my android device. The application run smoothly, the problem is that when I click the download button it seems that is not working giving me the error that the image is not been successfully downloaded.

Can anyone please help me to edit my code in order to work fine, I am working on it for the last few days and i got pretty confused

Thanks in regards

Comment: Might that can be helpful to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41849946/how-to-save-image-from-url-into-device-photo-gallery-using-ionic

Answer (score 0):

this line 
`const imageLocation ='${cordova.file.applicationDirectory}https://cdn.houseplans.com/product/o2d2ui14afb1sov3cnslpummre/w1024.jpg?v=15${image}';`

Why are you prepending application url to your link? As you are later passing it as url param to file transfer i suggest it should be just:
`'https://cdn.houseplans.com/product/o2d2ui14afb1sov3cnslpummre/w1024.jpg?v=15${image}';`

(please note that i replaced template quotes with single quotes to avoid conflict with stackoverflow code quotes, if copy-pasting please make sure to replace them back)