# How to store locally an image from URL?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ionic-framework, ionic-react

I am making an Ionic react native app. I need to store many images that are accessibles on a public URL *(example : [www.example.com/image.jpg](http://www.example.com/image.jpg))*.

I actually store a json tab with nativeStorage module. Now I would like to find a solution for some pictures. It could be great if that pictures were in the same folder that the app.

Thanks

```
FileTransferError {code: 3, source: "https://api.example.ch/content/project_name/image.jpg", target: "file:///data/user/0/ch.example.project_name/files/image.jpg", http_status: 401, body: null, …}
body: null
code: 3
exception: null
http_status: 401
source: "https://api.example.ch/content/project_name/image.jpg"
target: "file:///data/user/0/ch.example.project_name/files/image.jpg"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save image from URL into device photo gallery using ionic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41849946/how-to-save-image-from-url-into-device-photo-gallery-using-ionic)

Comment: i'm not familier with react so can't add a code as answer, but in the file plugin u can set data Directory or cache directory and others.... so they would be added within app directory and u can create a sub folder to save your data in it...

Comment: I see  your answer just now. I've just test it. I receive an error. But i think it's on the way. Do you know why it fail ?
Thanks already